# ImageMagick with Perl Script

Tags: perl, module, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to manipulate .jpg files.  I believe I have successfully installed it because I can convert a .jpg image to a .png image on the command prompt by the following command:

```
convert   image.jpg    image.png
```

However, when I attempt to load the module in a script and execute the script I get a “Can't locate imagemagick.pm in @INC (you may need to install the imagemagick module)” error.

How do I load the Image::Magick module into the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Image::Magick;   #load the ImageMagick module
use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory = 'path-to-images';

opendir my $dh2, $directory or die "Could not open file";

while (my $image = readdir($dh2)){
        my $convertedFileName = $image;  #assign current image to a variable
        $convertedFileName =~ s/.jpg/-convert.jpg/; #change name of file
        print "$convertedFileName\n";
        $convertedFileName = Image::Magick->new; #make ImageMagick object
        $convertedFileName->Quantize(colorspace=>'gray'); #alter the image
        }

closedir $dh2;
```

Comment: imagemagick has lots of backends, i.e. command line, perl, python... . You've obviously installed the command line but not the Perl backend.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php/ for how to install it.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install ImageMagick-perl

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ImageMagick-perl

Comment: Probably you have chosen the wrong package name. Try for example perlmagick: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=perlmagick

Comment: After you get the module installed, you'll also need to fix your while loop.  You're assigning the filename (without its path) to `$convertedFileName` then a couple lines later you wipe that out by reassigning that var to be to be an `Image::Magick` object.  I doubt that's what you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  For any future people needing ImageMagick with Perl      sudo apt-get install PerlMagick